# my program only prints out a bunch of "null"s when reading textfile

Tags: java, arrays, file-io

```
public class Song 
{
private String title;
private String artist;

public Song (String Title, String Artist)
{
    Title = title;
    Artist = artist;
}
public String toString()
{
    return (title +" "+ artist);
}
}
```

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class compactDisc 
{
 private Song[] arr = new Song[20];
 private int numSongs = 0;
 public compactDisc () throws IOException
 {
     int i=0;

     File file = new File ("song.txt");
     Scanner inputFile  = new Scanner(file);

     while (inputFile.hasNext()&& i<arr.length)
     {
         String Title = inputFile.nextLine();
         String Artist = inputFile.nextLine();
         arr[i] = new Song(Title,Artist);
         i++;
     }
     numSongs = i;
 }

 public String toString()
 {
    String str = "";
    for (int j = 0; j < numSongs; j++)
    {
        str += arr[j].toString();
    }   
        return str;
 }
}
```

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class collection 
{

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
{
    compactDisc cd = new compactDisc();
    System.out.println(cd);
}
}
```

This program is to display a list of songs and artist as a CD. The song class is the format of my prints, compactDisc class read a file that contains a list of songs and artists into an array, and main program prints them. However, when I run the program, it prints out `null nullnull nullnull nullnull nullnull nullnull null` instead of the actual list, and the direction seems correct. I wonder why that happens.

Answer (score 3):

check this here in your Song class.

```
private String title;
private String artist;

public Song (String Title, String Artist) {
   Title = title;
   Artist = artist;
}
```

you are assigning the null values that are not initialized from your Song class into the parameter and hence your classvariables will never be filled.

It should rather look like this

```
public class Song {
   private String title;
   private String artist;

   public Song (String title, String artist)  {
      this.title = title;
      this.artist = artist;
   }
}
```

Also by convention classes should start with a capital letter and variables should start with a small letter.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here

```
public Song (String Title, String Artist)
{
    Title = title;
    Artist = artist;
}
```

the parameter is Title but you're assigning title (which is null);

Change to:

```
title = Title;
artist = Artist;
```

Comment: yes, I knew this before, just became retartedly careless and didn't even notice XD

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the `Song` class, as explained in (my) comments:

```
public Song (String Title, String Artist)
{
    Title = title;   // assigns this.title into local Title
    Artist = artist; // assigns this.artist into local Artist
}
```